# Twilio and Beautiful Soup sending back syntax error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, twilio

I am using Python to run BeautifulSoup and Twilio APIs as a way to identify free food in my area.

I am using the following code that I wrote in notepad++ and then saved as experiment.py in my downloads folder.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
import re

url = 'https://postmates.com/new-york-city'
account_sid = 'XXX'
auth_token = 'XXX'
twilio_phone_number = '+15551254565'
my_phone_number = '+15551234567'

webpage = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.text, 'html.parser')

free_regex = re.compile('free')
all_strings = list(soup.stripped_strings)
free_food = [s for s in all_strings if free_regex.match(s.lower())]

if free_food:
body = 'Free Postmates!\n\n' + '\n'.join(free_food)
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
client.messages.create(
    body=body,
    to=my_phone_number,
    from=twilio_phone_number
)
```

When I attempt to run this in terminal by typing in cd downloads experiment.py, I get the following message.

File "experiment.py", line 25
    from=twilio_phone_number
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What could be causing this to occur. I don't see the syntax error here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from=twilio_phone_number
```

`from` is a keyword in python, change it to `from_` or something else.